# Add a CASE on a SUM when using conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table (called report) in SQL Server with millions of records so performance is a factor.

```
+---------+------------------------+---------+
| user_id | timestamp              | balance |
+---------+------------------------+---------+
|    1    |2021-04-29 09:31:10.100 |   10    |
|    1    |2021-04-29 09:35:25.800 |   15    |
|    1    |2021-04-29 09:36:30.550 |   5     |
|    2    |2021-04-29 09:38:15.009 |   100   |
|    3    |2021-04-29 10:36:30.550 |   50    |
|    3    |2021-04-29 10:38:15.009 |   250   |
+---------+------------------------+---------+
```

Here are the requirements :
I would like to group the opening balance, closing balance and net movement of all users between a date range.

I require 2 queries:

1. all movement greater than a variable threshold (lets call it 10)
2. all movement less than a variable threshold (lets call it 10)

The records must also be returned using the OFFET x FETCH NEXT y ROWS for a lighter response to the UI.

Here I have a working query that **does not** take into account the less than / greater than the threashold requirement.

```
select user_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then balance end) as opening,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then balance end) as closing,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 and seqnum_desc = 1 then 0
                when seqnum = 1 then - balance
                when seqnum_desc = 1 then balance
           end) as movement
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as seqnum_desc
      from report r where timestamp >= '2020-03-21 16:22:26.580' and timestamp <= '2022-03-24 16:22:26.580'
     ) r where timestamp >= '2020-03-21 16:22:26.580' and timestamp <= '2022-03-24 16:22:26.580' 
group by user_id order by user_id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
```

[Here is the DB fiddle to get the output below](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80b3a293a26fc7b8faa12657b32399f9)

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| user_id |     opening     |     closing     |   movement   |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    1    |       10        |       5         |     -5       |
|    2    |       100       |       100       |      0       |
|    3    |       50        |       250       |      200     |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

How do I conditionally return only movements greater than 10 and less than 10.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `OFFSET/FETCH` is not lighter except in the amount of rows returned to client. It still requires the server to read all rows up to the offset. For best performance, look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a CTE or subquery:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where movement < 10;  -- or whatever condition
```

Note:  You might actually want the absolute value if you really mean -10 to 10 rather than 0 to 10:

```
where abs(movement) < 10
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon, However the CTE in the above example will use the filtered results to test the condition. I require that all results be tested.

Comment: @Fuzz . . . Then leave the filtering out of the CTE.  Or move it to the outer query.